# How to replace values from variable A and B with NA if value of A is lower than value of B

Tags: r

How to replace values of variable-A and variable-B with NA if the variable-A value is smaller than the corresponding value in variable B. It is in R. I know that I have to use some sort of for-if-else statement, but I am lost.

Let's say I have a dataframe with 2 variables, A and B. And everytime the value of variable A is lower than the value of variable B, I want the values (from variable A and B) to be replaced with NA.

Comment: Try `replace(A, A < B, NA)`

Comment: For a two column data frame you can do `df[df$A < df$B, ] <- NA`.  If more than two columns you can do `df[df$A < df$B, c("A", "B")] <- NA`

Comment: H 1, this gives me the following error: missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Comment: Combining H 1's and thelatemail's suggestion, you can do `df[which(df$A < df$B), c("A", "B")] <- NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A = runif(5), B = runif(5))
df

          A         B
1 0.2875775 0.0455565
2 0.7883051 0.5281055
3 0.4089769 0.8924190
4 0.8830174 0.5514350
5 0.9404673 0.4566147
```

Indexing rows where `df$A < df$B` is `TRUE` and setting the values of columns `c("A", "B")` to `c(NA, NA)`

```
df[df$A < df$B, c("A", "B")] <- c(NA, NA)
```

`df` is now:

```
          A         B
1 0.2875775 0.0455565
2 0.7883051 0.5281055
3        NA        NA
4 0.8830174 0.5514350
5 0.9404673 0.4566147
```

## Edit: Handling NA cases

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A = runif(5), B = runif(5))
df[c(1, 5), 1] <- NA
df[c(1, 4), 2] <- NA
df

          A         B    
1        NA        NA
2 0.7883051 0.5281055
3 0.4089769 0.8924190
4 0.8830174        NA
5        NA 0.4566147
```

Set `A` and `B` to `NA`:

```
df[is.na(df$A) | is.na(df$B) | df$A < df$B, c("A", "B")] <- c(NA, NA)


          A         B
1        NA        NA
2 0.7883051 0.5281055
3        NA        NA
4        NA        NA
5        NA        NA
```

**or**:

Ignore rows with `NA` in A`and/or`B`:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A = runif(5), B = runif(5))
df[c(1, 5), 1] <- NA
df[c(1, 4), 2] <- NA
df

df[!is.na(df$A) & !is.na(df$B) & df$A < df$B, c("A", "B")] <- c(NA, NA)


          A         B
1        NA        NA
2 0.7883051 0.5281055
3        NA        NA
4 0.8830174        NA
5        NA 0.4566147
```

Comment: Thank you. But what to do if you have missing value in your dataset?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with them. If you want to skip them: `df[!is.na(df$A) & !is.na(df$B) & df$A < df$B, c("A", "B")] <- c(NA, NA)` or if you want to set them both to `NA`: `df[is.na(df$A) | is.na(df$B) | df$A < df$B, c("A", "B")] <- c(NA, NA)`

Comment: `which(df$A < df$B)` is also an option that will remove `NA` values from the comparison.